# What are Sat Chit and Ananda attributes of Nirguna Brahman?

Tags: vedanta, advaita, upanishads, brahman

Upanishads do say Brahman is formless. So how can formless Brahman be Sat(Existence) Chit(Consciousness) Ananda(Bliss)? Without attributes how can we define these 3 features for Brahman?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124896/discussion-on-question-by-sethu-srivatsa-koduru-what-are-sat-chit-and-ananda-att).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the etymology reason for the swarupa order in the construction of the word "Sat-chit-ananda"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28677/what-is-the-etymology-reason-for-the-swarupa-order-in-the-construction-of-the-wo)

Comment: "Sat Chit Ananda, Sat is that never changes, Truth, Absolute Being. Chit is consciousness. Ananda is bliss. Absolute Bliss Consciousness." - Maharishi. Sat does not mean existence. Sat means Absolute or Truth. Could you pls share the reference from where you got such a meaning? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Satchitananda is not the guna of the Brahman. It is how we experience this ultimate reality, and to use a common analogy, just like we can experience the warmth of sunlight without understanding it.

Comment: Hi.! Please cite sources for your answers. Kindly have a look at:  [Guidelines for users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Brahman is formless...without a center nor circumference.  Sat (Existence), Chit (Consciousness), and Ananda (Bliss) are how we experience Brahman...in the absence of ignorance.  These may be attributes, but not forms.  Sat (Existence) and Chit (Consciousness) are also formless...with no center or circumference.  Ananda (Bliss) appears to be a form, but it is not.  In the absence of ignorance, there is Bliss...causeless...without center or circirumference.

Comment: You should cite sources.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack exchange. Please update your answer with sources. Else answer can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Sat-chit-ananda is one thing not three. It is trying to capture the full essence of Brahman. It is the attributeless Brahman, the atoms of subjective reality (which is reality). It cannot be known and have attributes because it is also the knower.

I think that much is relatively uncontroversial.

Comment: Namaste and welcome to the site. While browsing around, Kindly have a look at: [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions)

Comment: Ok. Noted. Thanks.

Comment: @Archit I deleted an answer and edited another to be more in line w the guidelines. The other two answers seem ok.

Answer (score 0):

Satcitananda is the subjective experience of Brahman, so sat, cit and ananda point to the qualities of that experience rather than to qualities of Brahman.

Eg, Atma Bodha, verse 65:
"That all pervading, eternal blissful consciousness is seen within when one observes it through the eye of knowledge...."